# SUBINACL getting access denied

Tags: windows, mstdc

Im trying to get SUBINACL utility to just display information  of the MSDTC service.

Im typing subinacl /service mstdc   and I get an error 5 access denied

```
C:\temp>subinacl /service msdtc

msdtc - OpenService Error : 5 Access is denied.
Elapsed Time: 00 00:00:00
Done:        1, Modified        0, Failed        1, Syntax errors        0
Last Done  : msdtc
Last Failed: msdtc - OpenService Error : 5 Access is denied.
```

If I run the same command for DHCP service it gives me all the security. I am running it under the administrator.  Is there somewhere in the registry where I can fix this for the MSDTC ???

I am using Windows 2008 R2 64 Bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just spend few hours working on it, if you have the same problem you can reset ACL access list and add it then - just perform these lines from comamnd line (cmd) from admin account:

1. `sc sdset MSDTC D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)`
2. `subinacl /service msdtc /grant="Network Service"="QSETIL"*`

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue on Windows 7 Ultimate x64 SP1 when I was following the steps here:

http://pongsathonkeng.blogspot.com/2011/02/msdtc-setup.html

I think these are the steps to resolve the issue:

1. icacls c:\windows\system32\msdtc\msdtc.log /grant "networkservice":F

   As indicated here:

   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/eb8835d9-5f5b-4df2-8c68-4a61d5e44d6b/
2. subinacl /service msdtc /grant="Network Service"=QSETIL

   As also indicated here:

   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisforster/archive/2008/08/18/acl-problem-with-the-msdtc-service.aspx
3. restart